# Excel file generated with OpenXML (C#) is incomplete or corrupt somehow

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, openxml, asp.net-core-webapi

Ok, I am gonna be clearer about this:

Currently, I have a method inside my ASP.NET Core 2.1 project to generate an Excel file using OpenXML v2.8.1.

The file itself is generated well, I can open it in any Excel version in Mac/PC without any issue, but here comes the weird stuff: the final user can use this files for uploading them back to the application as it is, but when they try to do that, the app crashes because the input stream that receives the file is "incomplete" and although it contains bytes, it seems like it cannot be read.

This is very strange because the "fix" we have now is to open the file and save it (Ctrl + S) and that's it, even if you copy the file to another location, the problem is solved, but we want to avoid that. And we need to find out what's happening.

I am gonna share part of the code that generates that Excel file which is returned in an API as file in my React application for the UI:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                #region WORKBOOK SETUP

                WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

                Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

                Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "Sheet 1" };

                sheets.Append(sheet);

                SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());

                // Adding style
                WorkbookStylesPart stylePart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
                stylePart.Stylesheet = SpreadSheetUtilities.GenerateStyleSheet();
                stylePart.Stylesheet.Save();

                #endregion

                #region HEADERS
               //This part just appends the data into two rows in the current sheet
                #endregion

                #region BODY
                //This part appends the cell with the information
                #endregion

                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
            }
```

Comment: I suggest you add in enough stuff to create the memory stream and save it to a file.  That way, someone can grab your code as is, write out your file, open it in the OpenXml "Productivity Tool" to take a look at it, cuss at the fussiness of the api, etc.  When you work creating xlsx or docx files using OpenXml, you get very used to creating corrupted files.

Comment: If you can open the file, the written file is probably OK. It sounds like a stream might be open, or the file might be in use when they try to upload it. Office tends to like to control read access on its files, maybe it's open in Excel?